# How to browse a csv file, when the header line includes a null or empty value?

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

I have an A.csv file with 10 columns, all of which have a name except the last one.
I want to generate a new D.csv file with headers `"ID", "Type", "Name", "Documentation"`.
At first to work, I gave a name to this empty column, since I don't know how to read the values of a column that is empty in powershell.  I can not do for the type `"TechnologyEvent"` Please, can you help me?

fichier A.Csv

```
Jobstream,Jobstream Description,Op num, Job,Script or expected file(s), Server, user,location,Job Description,  
PAXCWEBX965H,"RMNF - xWEBX1","9","","technical","","","","Begin Of JobStream","05h00"
PAXCWEBX965H,"RMNF - xWEBX1","40","PWEBX0GJ","PWEBX-965H-005S.KSH","PRAXCWBXLBDD01","svc_bddo_user","F+WEBX-027","Lancement Sauv. RMAN","05h00"
```

Fichier D.csv

```
ID,"Type","Name","Documentation"
79570056-ab4f-6969-8c58-a5bd5847a895,"TechnologyInteraction","WEBX965H","RMNF - xWEBX1"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49498,"TechnologyService","WEBX965H-005S","Lancement Sauv. RMAN"
id-bdca3a1b39ed49cd80ae41deaa88094c,"TechnologyEvent","Lancement Sauv. RMAN  05:00",""
```

```
function newElements{

    process{
    
        # import data 
    $data = Import-csv -Path $env:USERPROFILE\A.csv -Delimiter ';'

        $NewExtract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925= ForEach($Entry in $ElementCsv){
  

 
    # -or [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Entry."Script or expected file(s)")
    if ( ($Entry."Script or expected file(s)" -ilike 'technical') -or [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Entry."Script or expected file(s)")  ) {
        $Entry."Jobstream"=$Entry."Jobstream" -replace '^(?:PAXC)?(.+?)','$1' 

    }

    else {
        $Entry."Jobstream" = $Entry.'Script or expected file(s)' -replace '^(?:P|A|X|C)?(.+?)(\.(?:BAT|KSH)|$)','$1' -replace '^(.{4})-','$1'
    }

        $Entry
    }
        # Export Extract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20211005.csv  in new B.csv file 
        $NewExtract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925  | Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\B.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
    
        $NewExtract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925Jobstream= Import-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\B.csv | Where { $oldElementsCsv.Name -notcontains $_.Jobstream}| Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\C.csv -NoTypeInformation  -Encoding UTF8 
        $ImportCsv=Import-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\C.csv
        #Output progress:
        $output= @()
        #Jobstream, Jobstream Description,Op num, Job,Script or expected file(s),Server, user, location, Job Description
        ForEach ($column in $ImportCsv){
        $pattern='^(.*)-'
        $pattern2='^(.*)_'
    if($column.Jobstream  -notmatch $pattern){

        $output1= New-Object PsObject -Property @{"ID"=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); "Type"="TechnologyInteraction"; "Name"= $column.Jobstream; "Documentation"=$column."Job Description" + " `r`nSever: $($column.Server)  `r`nuser: $($column.user) " ;  "Planification"= $column.Planification }   
        Write-Warning "Found new Jobstream : $($column.Jobstream)"
        Write-Warning "Found new Jobstream Description : $($column."Job Description")"
        $output= $output + $output1
    }  

  
          elseif($column.Jobstream  -match $pattern2) 
    {

        $output2= New-Object PsObject -Property @{"ID"=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); "Type"="TechnologyService"; "Name"=$column.Jobstream; "Documentation"= $column."Job Description"+ " `r`nSever: $($column.Server)  `r`nuser: $($column.user) " ; "Planification"= $column.Planification   } 
        Write-Warning "New Jobstream : $($column.Jobstream)"
        Write-Warning "New Jobstream Description : $($column."Job Description")"
        $output= $output + $output2

    } 
   elseif (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($column.Planification) ){

        $output4= New-Object PsObject -Property @{"ID"=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); "Type"="TechnologyEvent"; "Name"= $column."Job Description" + " " + $column.Planification ; "Documentation"= ""  } 

        Write-Warning "New Type TechnologyEvent : $( $column."Job Description")"
        Write-Warning "New Type TechnologyEvent Description : $($column."Job Description")"
        $output= $output + $output4

    }
    else{

        $output3= New-Object PsObject -Property @{"ID"=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); "Type"="TechnologyService"; "Name"= $column.Jobstream; "Documentation"= $column."Job Description" + " " + $column.Planification + " `r`nSever: $($column.Server)  `r`nuser: $($column.user)" } 

        Write-Warning "New Jobstream : $($column.Jobstream)"
        Write-Warning "New Jobstream Description : $($column."Job Description")"
        $output= $output + $output3
    }

 

    }
    $output |Select-Object -Property "ID","Type","Name","Documentation" -Unique| Export-Csv $path\D.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 

    #open new File:
    notepad $path\D.csv
    Write-Host "Ending newElements "
    }
}newElements
```

Comment: Your indentation is horrible.. Please fix that so it is clear when a foreach, if, elseif etc starts and ends. Then, your csv files in the examples use the **comma** as delimiter, so if that is the case in your real files remove `-Delimiter ';'`

Comment: "I gave a name to this empty column" - how? where? what empty column? If you want a CSV file with the columns `"ID","Type","Name","Documentation"`, you should create powershell objects with those four property names and pipe the objects to `Export-Csv` or `ConvertTo-Csv`.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify headers while importing a CSV with `-Headers`:

```
# I set the 10th column name to "Schedule".
# You need to skip the first row if the file contains a header already:
$header = ('Jobstream','StreamDescription','OpNum','Job','Script','Server','user','location','JobDescription','Schedule')
$data = Import-csv -Path $env:USERPROFILE\A.csv -Delimiter ';' -Header $header |
  Select -Skip 1
```

To create a custom csv, try using something like this:

```
$output = ForEach ($row in $ImportCsv) {
  [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
    "ID"=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); 
    "Type"="TechnologyInteraction"; 
    "Name"= $row.Jobstream; 
    "Documentation"="$($row.JobDescription) `r`nServer: $($row.Server)  `r`nnuser: $($row.user) " ;  
  }
}

$output | Export-Csv $path\D.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

The output in list format looks like so:

```
ID            : 85bf5f43-03fe-47af-9b04-84de8fe59f1c
Type          : TechnologyInteraction
Name          : PAXCWEBX965H
Documentation : Begin Of JobStream 
                Server:   
                nuser:  

ID            : 70e17ea9-2219-4836-b17f-9c9013a7ed6d
Type          : TechnologyInteraction
Name          : PAXCWEBX965H
Documentation : Lancement Sauv. RMAN 
                Server: PRAXCWBXLBDD01  
                nuser: svc_bddo_user
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For the second part, do you think, with  $data, I could create a hashtable "A" containing as value the schedule column and as key a generated ID in order to generate the TechnologyEvent type